# angular redirect to auth

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-routing

I try use Angular Cli and Routing.
I want made some routing
/auth/login as default
/auth/register ect

I have 3 module
app
   auth
      login
on each level module i have definied route
app.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'auth' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

app/auth.module

```
const routes: Routes =  [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    children: [
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login' },
      { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' },
      { path: 'register', loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterModule' },
    ]
  }
];
```

and in app/auth/login

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

After run my app I expect to be redirect to 
auth/login
but i have 404 page from

```
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
```

I don't understatement why it's happen
What I do wrong?
repository can be finded here:
https://bitbucket.org/kajzarowie/tst/src/ef5708f45465a2c1b5d598253352228be2d3bddd/src/app/?at=master

Comment: Where do you import the `AuthModule` into the app? I think you need to add it to the `imports` for the `app.module.ts`

Comment: that would prevend lazy loading ;)

Comment: in \src\app\app.module.ts, Is any better place for it?
After add it also  not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Solutions.
What I need do is add import  AuthModule in app-routing.module :)

Answer (score 0):

Redirect directly to login

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'auth/login' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

Comment: it's doesn't work. I look like they did not see the auth.module